# Is there a mongo operation for getting the count of documents in a sorted (and or filtered) collection after and before a provided document (_id)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

For example, with pymongo:

I'm adding new document like this with a sequential index.

```
DB_1 = mongo ["DB_1"]
collection_1 = DB_1 ["collection_1"]
collection_1.insert_one ({
    'emblem': collection_1.find ().sort ({ 
        "emblem": -1
    }).limit (1).next () ["emblem"] + 1,
    'name': 'W'
})
```

As you can see, the names have a sequential "emblem"
based on the order they were inserted (with most likely
sequential indexes missing if a document is removed)

```
[{
  "emblem": 1,
  "name": "Z"
},{
  "emblem": 2,
  "name": "H"
},{
  "emblem": 3,
  "name": "T"
},{
  "emblem": 4,
  "name": "Q"
},{
  "emblem": 6,
  "name": "L"
}]
```

Then, after the aggregate sort, listed below, the emblem order is 2, 6, 4, 3, 1

```
documents = collection_1.aggregate ([
    { 
        "$addFields": {
            "lowerName": { 
                "$toLower": "$name" 
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        #
        #   sort by name, and if names are same,
        #   then sort by emblem.
        #
        "$sort": { 
            "lowerName": 1,
            "emblem": 1
        }
    }
])
```

Then, after the aggregate sort is performed,
this algorithm calculates
the counts of document before and after
the document with a provided emblem.

```
emblem = 6

before = 0
after = 0
counting_before = True
counting_after = False
for document in documents:
    if (document ["emblem"] == emblem):
        counting_before = False
        counting_after = True
    elif (counting_before):
        before += 1
    elif (counting_after):
        after += 1

#
# after equals 1
# before equals 3
#
```

Is it possible to calculate these counts,
as part of the aggregator or with another mongo
query?

For context, I'd like to show something like this
in the browser, where the buttons would do a search with
the same search string, filter, and sorting.  However
they would have an additional input.  Next would
also have the last document in the current page,
and prev would have the first document in the current page.

```
[prev (32 documents)] [next (281 documents)]
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: @ray Thanks for the help, however unless I missing something, it doesn't seem like that calculates the count/tally/sum of documents in the sorted collection, after or before a provided document (emblem). It looks like that's more for creating a linked list type structure?

Comment: Oh sorry, the last code panel sort of has the input and output.  With emblem = 6, would be checking for after = 1 and before = 3.  As in with query result: 2, 6, 4, 3, 1, there is one document before 6, and 3 documents after.  Maybe $facet is on the right track, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @ray Yeah, that's like perfect actually, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$setWindowFields` with `$sum` and document window of ["unbounded", -1] and [1, "unbounded"] to count the number of documents before/after the current document.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "lowerName": {
        "$toLower": "$name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        "lowerName": 1,
        "emblem": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "before": {
          "$sum": 1,
          "window": {
            "documents": [
              "unbounded",
              -1
            ]
          }
        },
        "after": {
          "$sum": 1,
          "window": {
            "documents": [
              1,
              "unbounded"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vRbHtZDkLY6)